# combining a div thumbnail switching script with an image zoom script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, thumbnails

I am trying to get 2 different scripts working together ..

- one being a simple thumbnail switching script that changes the big image depending on which thumbnail is clicked, from http://bonrouge.com/br.php?page=imageswitch
- the other being an image zoom script, which zooms to a larger image depending on where the mouse is hovered, from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/featuredzoomer.htm

The problem is that it always shows the 2nd image, no matter if the thumbnail is switched to the first one or the second one. I assume it has something to do with the divs overlapping or something.

This is the combined code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#image-switch ul {
margin:0 0 0 20px;
color:red;
list-style-type:none;
}
#image-switch li {
padding:10px;
}
#image-switch #two, #image-switch #three, #image-switch #four, #image-switch #five {
display:none;
}
#radiobs {
width:150px;
position:relative;
margin:0;
}
#radiobs input {
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
margin-left:6em;
width:15px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.magnifyarea{ /* CSS to add shadow to magnified image. Optional */
box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px #818181;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow(color=#818181, offX=5, offY=5, positive=true);
background: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image-switch">

<div class="fright">
<div id="one">
<img id="image1" src="redsmall.jpg" height="193" width="150" alt="redsmall" />
<p>This is a red one.</p>
</div>
<div id="two">
<img id="image2" src="bluesmall.jpg" height="193" width="150" alt="bluesmall" />
<p>This is a blue one.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>



<ul>
<li><a onclick="switch1('one');">first frame</a></li>
<li><a onclick="switch1('two');">second frame</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="featuredimagezoomer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#image1').addimagezoom({
    zoomrange: [3, 10],
    magnifiersize: [450,350],
    magnifierpos: 'right',
    cursorshade: true,
    largeimage: 'redbig.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
})

$('#image2').addimagezoom({
    zoomrange: [3, 10],
    magnifiersize: [450,350],
    magnifierpos: 'right',
    cursorshade: true,
    largeimage: 'bluebig.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
})

})

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function switch1(div) {
var options, obj, id; 
if (document.getElementById(div)) { // change this to div instead of 'one'
    options=['one','two','three','four'];
    for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) { 
        id = options[i]; // caching the array item is good practice bc array/object     access is slow
        obj=document.getElementById(id);
        if (!obj) { continue; } // make sure the obj exists
        obj.style.display = (id === div) ? "block" : "none"; 
       }
   }
}
//
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any ideas what's wrong, I promise I'll name my firstborn after you!

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed two things that are wrong:

**1:**

You use `#image1` both times

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#image1').addimagezoom({
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [450,350],
        magnifierpos: 'right',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: 'redbig.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
    }); //use semicolons

    $('#image2').addimagezoom({ // **** image2 not image1!!! ****
        zoomrange: [3, 10],
        magnifiersize: [450,350],
        magnifierpos: 'right',
        cursorshade: true,
        largeimage: 'bluebig.jpg' //<-- No comma after last option!
    }); //use semicolons

}); //use semicolons
```

**2:**

You need to check if the div exists, instead of checking if 'one' exists every time. I've also make a couple other edits (see my comments in the code).

```
var switch1;
(function($){ // let's use jQuery, its on the page anyway
    switch1 = function(div) {
        var options, $obj, id; 
        if ($('#' + div).length) { // change this to div instead of 'one'
            options=['one','two','three','four'];
            for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) { 
                id = options[i]; // caching the array item is good practice bc array/object access is slow
                $obj=$('#' + id);
                if (!$obj.length) { continue; } // make sure the obj exists
                $obj.css({
                    "display": id === div ? "block" : "none",
                    "left": id === div ? "0" : "10000px"
                });
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:**
Since you are now seeing both, I think we need to make sure the hidden images are moved way off the screen (then we'll move them back). To do this, add update following css rule:

```
#two, #three, #four, #five { /* using two id selectors in a row is unnecessary */
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 10000px; /* move them wayyy off screen. */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I tried the above changes but unfortunately it's still not working. When I hover over the upper part of the image, it shows the "red" one, when I hover over the lower part, the "blue" one, no matter to which div I switch. Maybe it's because the divs are overlapping and hidden?

Comment: @user1227914 OK I've made a few edits. Update the CSS rule and the switch1 function as I've done and see if it works. Basically, I'm trying to move the hidden images off of the screen. I'm a little worried image1 will work, but when you switch to image2, it won't. If that is the case, you'll probably need to call the `addimagezoom` plugin every time you switch images. Let me know...

Answer (score 0):

Here ,you called two images:

```
  <img id="image1" src="redsmall.jpg" height="193" width="150" alt="redsmall" /> 
  <img id="image2" src="bluesmall.jpg" height="193" width="150" alt="bluesmall" />

These two images should be seen as you only applied zoom feature using jQuery.
 Probably,in style section..you need to make some modifications.

 Following seems to be erratic work. 
                <li><a onclick="switch1('one');">first frame</a></li>

  Here,this shud be da way
                <a=" " onclick="switch1();"> or <a=# onclick="switch1();">

Moreover,U got all divs stored in options..so u dun need div to be passed.
U can refer to option[index]..And also, document.getElementById(img).src would be         required.

I amnt providing you the code.But hope these informations help you..
```